# React Native Dynamically load modules/plugins?

Tags: dynamic, plugins, module, react-native, dynamic-library

As far as I've searched it appears to be impossible to load modules (=plugins/libraries?) dynamically (I'm very new to React Native..).

What I'd like to accomplish is to let the user of the app load additional functions as she/he desires.

Example:
A user wants to add a music plugin to the app.

Intuitively, I'd long for something like dynamic library loading. The user would fetch the library, it'll be loaded into the code and can then be executed. However, in React Native it seems like there are only modules that can be loaded?

Alternatively, I'd hope that auto-updating the app would allow to add modules "on-the-fly" ( https://github.com/aerofs/react-native-auto-updater or www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-hot-load ). But I fear that this is only for JS and data content?

The ability to dynamically add functionality to the app is an essential part of the app. I have no previous experience worth mentioning in mobile app development.

Question: Is it possible to dynamically add functionality (also native in nature) to React Native apps?
If not, would there be a workaround?

EDIT: I have found the following repository on github: https://github.com/yusefnapora/react-dynamic-linking-example .
Unfortunately, without any description. I have no idea about Objective-C, but the repo name sounds promising. Anybody knows what its purpose is?

Comment: The github repo you mentioned, does not seem to do anything special. As far as I can make out from the Objective C code.

Have you found a solution to this yet? I just started looking at react native myself. Will keep you updated if I find a solution.

Comment: So far not. I looked into https://flutter.io/ which seems interesting.
But tbh I've stopped looking into the issue for now.